# SwiftUI - Listening for authorization status on location permission

Tags: swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I am using SwiftUI to present a map using UIViewRepresentable, and getting the coordinates with CLLocationManager. So, in updateUIView, I am requesting authorization and checking authorization status in order to present the user's location, but authorization status is not determined the first time since code runs before user chooses whether to allow or deny permission. Normally, I would use CLLocation's delegate for listening to permission changes, but I don't know how to achieve this in SwiftUI, since UIViewRepresentable works only with structs.

Comment: Try to search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui%5D+CLLocationManager